# datepicker control: why the date's year is displaying two times?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I've a datepicker control in my website, when I click into a textbox, the datepicker is displaying:

[image]

But when I'm clicking into a date, I have a problem to display the date:

[image]

The year is displaying two times... But I don't know why... I've followed this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)

**Can you help me to find why the date's year is displaying two times please ?**

***Date.cshtml***

```
@model DateTime

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EditorHookup.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>

@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
              new { @class = "date" })

** TODO Wire up the date picker! **
```

*EditorHookup.js*

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".date").datepicker({
    //      buttonImage: "/content/images/calendar.gif",
    //      showOn: "both",
    //      defaultDate: $("#calendar-inline").attr('rel')
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

});
});
```

*Create.cshtml (View)*

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
```

*Model class*

```
public class Reservation
{
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Column("Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

*And finally Controller's create method*

```
// GET: /Reservation/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Reservation { Date = DateTime.Now.Date});
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be in your EditHookup.js in this line:

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

Try changing to:

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```